# Combining Observable's within an Observable of an Array

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have (what I think) should be a common scenario.

I have a ViewModel that may have child view models. Both (parent and children) have an `Observable<Bool>` to reflect if they have changes respect to their original state.

The code looks as follows:

```
class ParentViewModel {
    var children = Variable<[ChildViewModel]>([])

    var hasChanges: Observable<Bool> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(children.value.map { $0.hasChanges })
            .map { (boolArray) in
                boolArray.reduce(false) { $0 || $1 }
        }
    }
}

class ChildViewModel: CustomStringConvertible {

    let title: Variable<String>
    private let originalValue: String

    var hasChanges: Observable<Bool> {
        return title.asObservable()
            .map { $0 != self.originalValue }
    }

    init(string: String) {
        title = Variable<String>(string)
        originalValue = string
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(type(of: self)) - \(title.value)"
    }

}
```

This works fine, except `ParentViewModel` has changes is combining values from `children.value`, so it's not a true `Observable` (if I add a `ChildViewModel` after the binding of `hasChanges`, it won't be taken into account).

What I want is `ParentViewModel` `hasChanges` to be `true` if *any* of it's children `hasChanges` is true as well.

Another failed attempt, looks as follows:

```
children.asObservable()
    .flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
    .flatMap { $0.hasChanges }
```

This will return the latest value of the last child that had any changes, but if two children have changes and one returns to the original value, it makes it return `false`, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *.reduce()* emits only when upstream completes. Try using *.scan()* instead.

Another approach might be applying *.merge()* to all children observables and doing *.combineLatest()* on top of that.